# What is Mach number = 0?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, flow, speed

If you look at a paper on fluid dynamics, you will see a paper that is performing CFD simulation with a mach number of 0. This means that the flow velocity is 0, so I thought that no flow would occur, but when I looked at the results, the flow existed and emitted vortices. What does mach number = 0 mean?

Comment: Can you cite the paper?

Comment: "Compressibility effects on roughness-induced boundary layer transition" Matteo Barnardini, Sergio Pirozzoli, Paolo Orlandi 2012

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Often when fluid mechanicians refer to zero-Mach flows, the implication is not that the flow velocity is zero but that the speed of sound is infinitely large.

This usually implies that acoustic disturbances and other transient physical phenomena related to compressibility propagate away from their sources infinitely fast, which leads to considerable simplifications in the analysis of compressible flows.

Comment: I understood! thank you!